# Jquery how to find last child

Tags: jquery

For those who know JQuery - must be effort less question - 
I'd like to get the elemenet which is the **last** child of another element (of type 'input' that I know its ID ('myID'). 
What is the correct query:
I tried:

```
$("input:last-child", $("#myID")); 
 $("#myID input:last-child")
```

But it didn't work

Comment: Why would they not work? What's your HTML structure?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
$("#myID input:last") //for the last

$("#myID input:first") //for the first
```

Comment: Note: Because :last is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS specification, queries using :last cannot take advantage of the performance boost provided by the native DOM querySelectorAll() method. To achieve the best performance when using :last to select elements, first select the elements using a pure CSS selector, then use .filter(":last"). From http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/

Answer (score 0):

You can use last method too. Something like this:

```
$("#myID").last();
```

But make sure that you have jquery 1.4.X. While **:last** matches only a single element, **:last-child** can match more than one: one for each parent.

and i think what you have write will work in this way..

```
$("#myID input:last-child").val();
```

Comment: These are two fundamentally different things though - .last() is the last element in a collection of objects. So $("#myID").last() will be the same as $("#myID"), presuming that there's only one #myID. I think this chap may mean $("#myID").children().last();